# Bootstrap class navbar-light doesn't let me change the text color of A tags

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website using bootstrap css to make it quicker and easier but I ran into a issue with not being able to change the font-color when navbar-light is there but I can change it when navbar-light isn't there.

Tried removing the navbar-light class which makes it work but then when I adjust the width of my screen the 3 line thing for mobile users to get navigation does not work.

```css
body {
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

/* Branding */
.navbar-brand {

}

/* Navigation class */
.navbar {
    background-color: #3bb558;
}

/* Ul element for navigation */
.navbar-nav {
}

/* List items for navigation */
.nav-item {
}

/* A tag for navigation */
.nav-link {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="/img/logo.png" width="150" height="50">
        </a>
            <!-- On smaller screens there will be a button for dropdown navigation. -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Runescape Max Main Rentals</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Runescape PK Rentals</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>    
</body>
```

Comment: have you tried using `!important`?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your `.nav-link` [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is not stronger than the one defined in Bootstrap.

In BT4 with `navbar-light` added, this is the default CSS for `.nav-link`:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

While working with some CSS libs, the best way to override is to copy and paste their own CSS selector and change it in other places, just make sure it loads later.

So, your solution would be like this:

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: white;
}
```

In your case and for best practice, you can add your own prefix CSS at the root level or at the same level, this will make the CSS specificity stronger.

At the root level:

```
.root-project-name .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: white;
}
```

At the same level:

```
.root-project-name.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: white;
}
```

Notice the same level example (there is **NO SPACE** between `.root-project-name` and `.navbar-light`, in this case your HTML would look like this:

```
<div class="root-project-name navbar-light">
 ....
</div>
```

Some rules of thumb to remember by:

> Always look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important
>
> Only use !important on page-specific CSS that overrides foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or normalize.css).
>
> Never use !important when you're writing a plugin/mashup.
>
> Never use !important on site-wide CSS

Comment: This answer is more specific to bootstrap and basically hits points that I mentioned -- I would mark this one as correct

Comment: please notice the two examples I've added, this might help your project easier to inspect

Answer (score 0):

In the case of overriding another style, you can always try to use `!important` in your CSS style attribute declaration.

For example, if the `navbar-light` class is giving the text a white color, you may be able to override it by setting the text in your CSS:

```
.text-element {
    color: black !important;
}
```

Using `!important` should not be your first solution, but it can be useful for testing and can occasionally be used if there's a third-party library or framework that is setting CSS rules a certain way. If setting `!important` does change the text color, then you can try to take a look at the specificity of the CSS rules inside your browser's dev tools. For instance:

```
.container p .specific {
   color: white;
}

.container p {
    color: black;
}
```

The first rule above will override the second one because it's more specific. If there's a way you can be more specific in your own CSS rule, you may be able to set the CSS ruling how you want it without using `!important` or, even crazier, JavaScript.